# I cant compile program that uses class and list

Tags: c++, list, function, class

I wrote a program that allows the user to enter 3 names, and then displays the list of the names.

I cant compile this program. The error message says "error: request for member ‘list’ in ‘input’, which is of non-class type ‘Name()’
  input.list(); "

I dont understand what I did wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<list>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Name
{
    std::list<string> namelist;
    public:
    Name();
    void list();
};

Name::Name()
{
    int i;
    string input[i];
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {

        cout<<"Insert name: "<<input[i]<<endl;
        namelist.push_front(input[i]);
    }

}

void Name::list()
{

    for (std::list<string>::iterator NL = namelist.begin(); NL !=  namelist.end(); NL++)
    std::cout << *NL << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main()
{

    Name input();
    input.list();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Name input();` is a declaraion of function. You want `Name input;` or `Name input{};`. Search [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) for more details.

Comment: Isn't it a bit confusing calling a member function `list`, while using `std::list`?

Comment: `cout<<"Insert name: "<<input[i]<<endl;` - I *think* you are trying to enter the names here. If ythat's so, this is not the way to go. This is a pure *output* operation, you'll need something like `cin >> blah`.

Comment: Watch out for `string input[i];` `i` doesn't have a value yet, and it's a non-Standard [Variable Length Array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main()`, `Name input();` is not a definition of object, should be:

```
Name input;
```

---

I think what you want to do in constructor of `Name` is:

```
Name::Name()
{
    const int SIZE = 3;
    string input[SIZE]; // size of array should be const
    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << "Insert name: " << endl;
        cin >> input[i];
        namelist.push_front(input[i]);
    }
}
```

And can be improved. Since `input` only used to store temporary value, there is no need to use array:

```
Name::Name()
{
    const int SIZE = 3;
    string input; // only stores temporary value, no need to use array
    for (int i = 0; i<SIZE; i++)
    {
        cout << "Insert name: "  << endl;
        cin >> input;
        namelist.push_front(input);
    }
}
```